# Numerical integration of Hereditary Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function, numerical-calculus

$$\sigma(t) =\int_{0}^{t}E(t-\tau) \frac{d\epsilon(\tau)} {d\tau} d\tau$$

I am trying to integrate the above equation and impliment the same in FORTRAN, to solve for the material behavior of a visco elastic material.
$\epsilon(t)$ is the strain on the material and $\sigma$ is the stress developed.

Here,
$E(t-\tau)=E_0*exp(t-\tau)$.

I tried to solve it using integration by parts with no success.
Could someone please point me right direction in how to numerically integrate this equation so that I can impliment it in FORTRAN.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\frac{\partial}{\partial\tau}E(t-\tau)=-E(t-\tau)$, integrating by parts gives
$$
\sigma(t)=E(0)\epsilon(t)-E(t)\epsilon(0)+\int_0^t E(t-\tau)\epsilon(\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau
$$
Note that with equally-spaced nodes, you can easily reuse the previous evaluations since $E(t+h-\tau)=e^h E(t-\tau)$.